# MYSQL: encounter ERROR 1064 when trying to delete row

Tags: mysql

when i execute following command, it can print some records

```
mysql> select *  from table_name where domain like "%com";
+---------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+----------+
| date                | domain       | percent            | flow1     | flow2    |
+---------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+----------+
| 2021-10-13 21:00:00 | www.a.com    |                 20 |    544.93 |      109 |
| 2022-05-26 21:00:00 | www.b.com    |              23.28 |     64.81 |    15.09 |
```

but when i execute delete, it print some error

```
mysql> delete  from table_name where domain like "%com";
ERROR 1064 (HY000): Where clause should be compound or binary predicate
```

what is the mean of above error? and how to solve it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your commands work for me, including the delete command. Maybe you could add some more information about your mysql version and the types you're using for your data?

Comment: Mine works as well. And I was using your exact statements. Please provide more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message for `error 1064` on MySQL server have the next pattern:

```
%s near '%s' at line %d
```

See [Server Error Message Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html).

You receive another message text - hence it is not produced by MySQL. Either your DBMS is not MySQL or the error message printed is an interpretation of the MySQL error message made by the client.

1. Ensure that your DBMS is MySQL really. Execute `SELECT VERSION();` and provide complete output for this command.
2. Ensure that you use command-line client `mysql.exe` installed as a part of MySQL server installation, and not another tool which looks like CLI.

Additionally - show the output for `SELECT SESSION sql_mode;`.

Comment: @Luooke And what was the reason of your issue?

Comment: I consulted my colleague, Real DBMS is Doris, it seems that delete operation doesn't support  `like`.

Comment: @Luooke https://doris.apache.org/docs/sql-manual/sql-reference/Data-Manipulation-Statements/Manipulation/DELETE.html#description - only `=, >, <, >=, <=, !=, in, not in` on the key column can be specified.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I try to use `in`, but failed, it still print above error ~
i. i use insert command insert target domain into for_test table
ii. exec follow command:
`DELETE FROM table_name WHERE domain IN (
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT domain FROM for_test
) AS p
);`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely the double quotes you used for the string literal following `LIKE`.  This may spoof MySQL into thinking that you are trying to refer to a column by that name.  Instead, always use single quotes for string literals:

```sql
DELETE
FROM table_name
WHERE domain LIKE '%com';
```

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely, i try to use single quotes, it still print above error.